# ImportError: cannot import name when using Jenkins CI but can't reproduce locally

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, bazel

```
ImportError: cannot import name CustomUtils
```

The import line is:

```
from root.src.custom import Customutils
```

This is the error I get at my work's codebase for a pull request that I submitted. However, this error seems to only show up when using our unit test suite on Jenkins with bazel.

When I run the same test locally, I cannot reproduce this error, and there are no circular dependency issues. So I'm perplexed as to what could be going on in the unit tests on Jenkins but it works fine locally?

I'm also not well versed with Python so I'm not sure if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: I think it might be a bazel issue. I think I need to add something to the `BUILD` file so we'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: 1. Check if the module is installed: Ensure that the "Customutils" module is installed on the Jenkins server. You can check this by running pip list or pip freeze on the Jenkins server and looking for the module name in the output.

2. Check the Python version: Make sure that the Python version used on the Jenkins server is the same as the one you are using locally. You can check the Python version by running python --version on the Jenkins server.